# Scrape Dynamic Data in Fangraphs using RSelenium

Tags: r, web-scraping, rselenium

I'm trying to automate the download of dynamic data from fangraphs. The goal would be to mimic clicking the "Export Data" link that downloads a csv. OR, if possible, simply scrape the data. Either method of getting the data is fine with me. I've tried the following code in RSelenium to no avail:

```
remDr <- remoteDriver(port = 4445L,
            browserName = 'firefox')
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("https://www.fangraphs.com/leaders/splits-leaderboards?splitArr=1,7&splitArrPitch=&position=B&autoPt=false&splitTeams=false&statType=player&statgroup=1&startDate=2017-03-01&endDate=2021-11-01&players=&filter=&groupBy=career&sort=-1,1")
remDr$findElement(using = "class", value = "data-export")
```

The data for this URL is rendered using javascript. Although you can inspect the elements on the page and see the class = "data-export" element, the remDr$findElement returns an error:

```
Selenium message:Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"data-export"}
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
System info: host: '7d65bd0674cb', ip: '172.17.0.2', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.4.0-80-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_91'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown

Error:   Summary: NoSuchElement
     Detail: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
     class: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException
     Further Details: run errorDetails method
```

Comment: I cannot replicate your problem. `remDr$findElement` do not return any error. See the output here: https://pastebin.com/VE8jmGc4 I only used `remDr <- rsDriver(port = 4445L, browserName = 'firefox')` instead of `remoteDriver` but, in my opinion, it cannot be the cause of your problem.

Comment: Could be a timing issue. Does adding an explicit wait before resolve it?

Comment: @QHarr: I added various wait times up to 100000 milliseconds and receive the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `class` try `xpath`

```
library(RSelenium)
driver = rsDriver(port = 4941L, browser = c("firefox"))
remDr <- driver[["client"]]
remDr$navigate("https://www.fangraphs.com/leaders/splits-leaderboards?splitArr=1,7&splitArrPitch=&position=B&autoPt=false&splitTeams=false&statType=player&statgroup=1&startDate=2017-03-01&endDate=2021-11-01&players=&filter=&groupBy=career&sort=-1,1")

#Click Exporrt Data 

remDr$findElement(using = "xpath",'//*[@id="react-drop-test"]/div[2]/a') -> downloaddata
downloaddata$clickElement()
```